# Написание своего языка программирования

Tags: c++

в голову пришла мысль о написании своего языка программирования. Я ничего не знаю по этому вопросу и решил обратиться к пользователям Stack Overflow.
Можете рассказать что к чему(про сам процесс создания).
И желательно пояснить не сложным языком.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "Как написать свой язык программирования, не привлекая внимания санитаров."

Comment: Начните с изучения [классики](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1349-4.html) - это в теории. В практике - напишите для начала простенький калькулятор. Можно - программируемый. Это очень полезно. Если получится - вы сможете оценить сложность задачи, если нет - то тем более ее оцените :) Потому что пояснить тут "не сложным" языком то, что люди излагали более чем на 1000 страниц - не многим более реально, чем написание своего языка программирования, ничего не зная по этому вопросу и надеясь, что консультации на ruSO будет достаточно...

Comment: Почитайте [Пратт Т. "Языки программирования. Разработка и реализация"](http://www.studmed.ru/pratt-t-yazyki-programmirovaniya-razrabotka-i-realizaciya_faf17bd5a97.html) (в самом деле классная книга)

Answer (score 4):

> И желательно пояснить не сложным языком

Невозможно. Это очень сложная тема, требующая большого объёма крайне непростых знаний. Попробуйте осилить "книгу дракона":

[image: Книга дракона]

Как минимум она даст вам темы и направления для изучения.

Comment: Хех наконец-то я узнал что такое "книга дракона". Редко ее с полки достаю, даже не обращал внимания что там за дракон нарисован. В свою очередь могу посоветовать Льюис Ф., Розенкранц Д., Стирнз Р. "Теоретические основы проектирования компиляторов". Несмотря на слово "теоретические", это самое лучшее практическое руководство по написанию компиляторов из тех, что я видел. А вообще, если нет задачи сделать коммерческий компилятор, то проще всего почитать про контекстно-свободные грамматики, да и реализовать ее на Yacc(Bison).

Comment: И SICP ещё может быть полезен.

Answer (score 4):

1. Вначале нужна идея. Идей может быть много, например: язык должен быть объектно-ориентированным или процедурным или событийным или построенным на формальное логике предикатов (Пролог) или на реляционной алгебре (SQL) - ну и т.д.
2. Далее определяем семантику языка, то есть набор формальных правил, которым должна подчиняться грамматика языка - обычно сейчас этим мало кто себя утруждает и все живут в [семантике BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)
3. Далее придумываем синтаксис языка - принято описывать в форме BNF
4. Пишем под придуманный синтаксис парсер (создание парсера сейчас автоматизировано, грубо говоря засовываем форму BNF и на выходе готовый парсер на C или Java)
5. Под парсер пишем компилятор, то есть то что транслирует в машинные коды
6. Существует дальше специальный процесс под названием [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) - когда исходные тексты компилятора еще раз компилируются самим компилятором.

Считаю, что каждый уважающий себя программист хоть раз в жизни должен написать свой язык программирования - я лично написал аж несколько. И кстати, в этом нет ничего необычного часто приходится придумывать нечто, которое тянет на полноценный язык программирования.

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что нужно!